# Export imports with Golang

Tags: go

Not sure if this is impossible with Golang. With Node.js, I would do it like so:

```
import * as person from './person';
export {person};
```

with Golang I have `models.go`:

```
package models

import (
    "huru/models/person"
)
```

is it possible to export person from this models.go file, in a person namespace like with TypeScript/node.js?

Answer (score 12):

> [I]s it possible to export person from this models.go file, in a person namespace like with TypeScript/node.js?

No.

Comment: kinda lame but I can live with it

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this? Why wouldn't whatever is importing `models` just import `huru/models/person`?

Comment: It could just import `huru/models`, and then do `models.person.X`, not a big deal, just a different way of organizing things. When you have a lot of models that change/update, it's a nicety.

Comment: @MrCholo And in practice you won't worry much about this; any decent Go text editor / IDE will automatically add the proper imports for you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton this is not about the import paths, but about the identifiers you get after the import. `models.person.X` reads more clearly in some cases than just `person.X`.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot just pass through a complete package. You can pass through different types by making your own types based on them. If there was a `person.Person`:

```golang
package models

import (
    "huru/models/person"
)

type Person person.Person

//or

type EmbeddedPerson struct{
    person.Person
    additional string
}
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to add your own functions

```golang
func (p Person) CustomFunc() {}
```

Here is a playground link that shows some of the nuances of this: https://play.golang.org/p/1aLOcmsXHV2

Comment: The benefit of using the embedded approach, is that EmbeddedPerson will have all the  receiver methods of Person, so it automatically implements the same interfaces. I use this technique to re-export custom error types

Answer (score 1):

@MrCholo there is a little difference in golang concept here. The golang structs available under namespace scoped.

Like as per example

```
package models

// struct name should starts with Capital letter to export
type Person struct {
    Name string
    age int
}
```

The `Person` struct will be available in all files scoped under same namespace(ex. `models`). You don't need to import that.

But if you would like to access outside the `models` namespace you'll have to import the package `models` and access the `Person` object using that.

ex.

```
package anotherpackage

import (
    "<path to models>/models"
)

var perObj models.Person  // here is how you can access the Person struct
```

Let me know if it's still not clear to you.

Answer (score -1):

No.

You can use like this, for example custom log

```
package customLog

import "log"

func Print(args ...interface{}) {
  log.Print(args)
}
```

---

```
package example

func some() {
  customLog.Print("hi babay")
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, We can export struct from file to another file(or package) like other languages.

> person.go

```
package models

// struct name should starts with Capital letter to export
type Person struct {
    Name string
    age int
}
```

If the importing file is in the same package(models), then no need to import. Straight away you can use like this:

> details.go

```
package models

var perObj Person

func abc() {
    perObj.Name = "xyz"
}
```

If the importing file is in some other package, then import models package.

> businesslogic.go

```
package logic

import (
    "../../models"
)

var perObj Person

func abc() {
    perObj.Name = "xyz"
}
```

Comment: this question/OP is about exporting the Person type from the logic package

Comment: Exporting Person type from model package (from person.go file) to logic package.

Comment: Exporting Person type from logic package. Is what I want to do.

Comment: Then reverse my solution. Define Person type in any go file under logic package. Then use it wherever you want across the project.